# ngModel does not work on modal page in Ionic 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic/Angular app and wanted to use ngModel as alwayls. I am opening a modal from a modal and then want to use it like:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="stacked">Name des Rezepts</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="model" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-button (click)="save()">Save</ion-button>
```

i declared the variable in typescript like:

```
public model="";
```

But when i click save, my output IS ALWAYS the empty string?!

I imported ReactiveFormsModule in my app.module.ts and on normal pages it works, but in modals it seems like that it does not work?!

Do you guys have any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Try with another variable name? Like `textModel`? Because `model` looks suspisciously like a reserved keyword

Comment: Check the ngModule that declare modal component and make sure you imported FormModule on that ngModule

Comment: If you initialize with value: `public model = 'testing'` does `save()` keeps returning only 'testing' as value? Also, check `save()` method for typos.

Answer (score 0):

You take a look at this example ( same as yours ) https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-mqyzyh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html it works as expected.
So check your imports in your module ( but without modules you'll get an error anyway ).
Out of topic, you don't need 2 way binding. You're updating the value from the input ( at least in this example ).